# I am manually putting ID generated via POST method in PUT,GET method, How to Auomate it

Tags: java, rest-api, postman, rest-assured, rest

ISSUE- Using post method, ID get generated in response(id=ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b), now I don't want to put this id generated in PUT,DELETE,GET, manually(as I am doing below)

Can you please help

url =https://api.restful-api.dev/
selenium ECLIPSE IDE

```
//** POST METHOD** 
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://api.restful-api.dev/";
        String Response=given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .body(payload.computers()).when().post("objects")
        .then().log().all().statusCode(200)
        .header("Server", "cloudflare").extract().response().asString();
        
        System.out.println(Response);
    
    //****update the     "id": "ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b",****

    
        given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .body(payload.comp_put()).when().put("objects/ff80818188956aa601889b12c1ae0442")
        .then().assertThat().log().all().statusCode(200);
    
        
        //****GET METHOD the     "id": "ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b",****
        
        String getidresponse=given().log().all().queryParam("id","ff80818188956aa601889b12c1ae0442")
        .when().get("objects/ff80818188956aa601889b12c1ae0442")
        .then().log().all().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();
        JsonPath js = new JsonPath(getidresponse);
        
        
        //DELETE THE ID --->id = ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b
        
        given().log().all().queryParam("id","ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b")
        .when().delete("objects/ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b")
        .then().log().all().statusCode(200).body("message", equalTo("Object with id = ff80818188956aa6018899e27b76038b has been deleted."));



//**BODY**
public static  String  computers()

      {
        
        return "{\r\n"
                + "   \"name\": \"Apple MacBook Pro 16\",\r\n"
                + "   \"data\": {\r\n"
                + "      \"year\": 2019,\r\n"
                + "      \"price\": 1849.99,\r\n"
                + "      \"CPU model\": \"Intel Core i9\",\r\n"
                + "      \"Hard disk size\": \"1 TB\"\r\n"
                + "   }\r\n"
                + "}";
                
      }
      
      
      public static  String  comp_put()

      {
        
        return "{\r\n"
                + "   \"name\": \"Apple MacBook Pro 16\",\r\n"
                + "   \"data\": {\r\n"
                + "      \"year\": 2019,\r\n"
                + "      \"price\": 2049.99,\r\n"
                + "      \"CPU model\": \"Intel Core i9\",\r\n"
                + "      \"Hard disk size\": \"1 TB\",\r\n"
                + "      \"color\": \"white\"\r\n"
                + "   }\r\n"
                + "}";
                
      }
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting and strip off any unnecessary code, explaining step-by-step what you tried to do and what is the result.

Comment: If you know the form your initial response will take, then wouldn't Rest Assured provide methods to turn it into an object so you can simply use serialize/deserialize to extract the ID? (I'm familiar with a similar C# library, not Rest Assured

Answer (score 0):

To automate the process of retrieving the ID generated by the POST method and using it in subsequent PUT, GET, and DELETE methods, you can make use of RestAssured library with Java. I prefer to use Eclipse IDE to write and run my code.

Here's an example of how you can automate this process:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

public class AutomationScript {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Execute the POST request
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.restful-api.dev/";
        String response = given()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(payload.computers())
            .when()
            .post("objects")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .response()
            .asString();
        
        // Extract the ID from the response using JSONPath
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
        String id = jsonPath.getString("id");
        
        System.out.println("Generated ID: " + id);
        
        // Use the ID in subsequent requests
        // PUT method
        given()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(payload.comp_put())
            .when()
            .put("objects/" + id)
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
        
        // GET method
        String getResponse = given()
            .queryParam("id", id)
            .when()
            .get("objects/" + id)
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .response()
            .asString();
        
        System.out.println("GET Response: " + getResponse);
        
        // DELETE method
        given()
            .queryParam("id", id)
            .when()
            .delete("objects/" + id)
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("message", equalTo("Object with id = " + id + " has been deleted."));
    }
    
    // BODY payload
    public static String computers() {
        return "{\r\n"
            + "   \"name\": \"Apple MacBook Pro 16\",\r\n"
            + "   \"data\": {\r\n"
            + "      \"year\": 2019,\r\n"
            + "      \"price\": 1849.99,\r\n"
            + "      \"CPU model\": \"Intel Core i9\",\r\n"
            + "      \"Hard disk size\": \"1 TB\"\r\n"
            + "   }\r\n"
            + "}";
    }
    
    public static String comp_put() {
        return "{\r\n"
            + "   \"name\": \"Apple MacBook Pro 16\",\r\n"
            + "   \"data\": {\r\n"
            + "      \"year\": 2019,\r\n"
            + "      \"price\": 2049.99,\r\n"
            + "      \"CPU model\": \"Intel Core i9\",\r\n"
            + "      \"Hard disk size\": \"1 TB\",\r\n"
            + "      \"color\": \"white\"\r\n"
            + "   }\r\n"
            + "}";
    }
}
```

In this example, we first execute the POST request to generate the ID. Then, we use JSONPath to extract the ID from the response. We store the ID in the id variable and use it in subsequent requests (PUT, GET, and DELETE).

With this automation script, you can dynamically retrieve the ID generated by the POST method and use it in other HTTP methods without manual intervention.